# ORA-00600: internal error when using Oracle sorted hash cluster

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm currently testing Oracle's hash cluster feature with 11g(11.2.0.1.0). But whenever I use the sort keyword to create a sorted hash cluster, various internal error pop up. The trace file didn't offer any hint too.

e.g.

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kdqs_internal_single_row_enqueue_fip_failure], [1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kksfbc-wrong-kkscsflgs], [199177712008], [33], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

(latest)
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [25027], [4], [4294901761], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

I was looking for any clue on a proper reason for these errors, but only to find few people have tried this major feature. I know the correctness of hash cluster in Oracle is doubtful, but can I at least find a way to make it function?

Comment: "*ORA-00600: internal error code*" means you need to open a ticket with Oracle support - but you won't be very lucky as 11.2.0.1.0 is no longer supported. The last 11.2 release that is supported is 11.2.0.4

Comment: No luck for me since I am not a support customer ;(

Answer (score 1):

I am just trying to help you here.

This is what I found from the Web that flushing the shared pool, in this case, might help you.

Following are the details:

**Description:**

ORA-600 [kksfbc-wrong-kkscsflgs] / ORA-600 [kksfbc-5wrong-kkscsflgs]
can occur along with high CPU consumption under kksSearchChildList()
and waits on event '**cursor: mutex S**' for SQL with multiple versions.

**Workaround:**

Flush the shared pool

**Note:**
Bug 9066130 for one-off requests for 11.1.0.7.x and older versions (per Bug 9439258)
Bug 9067282 for one-off requests for 11.2.0.1.0 and later.

**Note:** This is the only summary. You can always consult with Oracle Support for advice. But before consulting try to gather information and solve it from above details.

**References**

Bug:9066130 (for PUBLISHED bugs)

Note:245840.1 Contains information on this.

Content is copied from the WEB and Oracle materials, just to help you in finding all the things in one place.

Cheers!!

Comment: many thanks for sharing, though this fix doesn't help right now.

Comment: I have not used my account to fetch the information. I have used only details available for public usage. Don't worry